# Kendo UI Grid Showing JSON Object as [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I am passing a function to one of the Kendo Grid field in fetch method. The function return perfectly on console.log, however in Kendo Grid, only [object Object] is return.

Here is the situation. There are two services that I am currently using:
1. ReviewService
2. UserService
The data in Kendo Grid is return by using **ReviewService**. One of the data is **"id"**. I created a function to find the **username** from **UserService** based on the "id". So, I use the function in the fetch method.

**Fetch Method**

```
protected fetch(state: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    this.loading = true;
    this.pagination = new Pagination(state.skip, state.take);

  return this.ReviewService.getByCriteria(this.pagination, this.apiVisa)
    .pipe(
      map(
        response =>
          <GridDataResult>{
            data: response["objectList"].map(review => ({
              id: review.id,
              email: this.displayUser(review.id)
            })),
            total: response["totalRecords"]
          }
      ),
      tap(() => (this.loading = false))
    );
  }
```

**Function**

```
public getUser(value): Observable<any> {
  return this.UserService.getByGuid(value, this.apiVisa);
}

public displayUser(id) {
    console.log("GUID: ", id);
    return this.getUser(id)
      .pipe(
      map((x: any) => 
        x.data
      ))
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.getItem = x.username;
        // return this.getItem;
        console.log("Username: ", x.username);
        return x.username;
        // return this.getItem;
      })
  }
```

**Expected Results**
In Kendo Grid: Adibah
In console.log: Adibah

**Actual Results**
In Kendo Grid: [object Object]
In console.log: Adibah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `displayUser` method you return a `Subscription` not the actual `x.username`. You can't just return the function in the `.subscribe` to pass it's value. You can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) operator to wait for the second observable to finish.

So you have to remove the `.subscribe` from your `displayUser` and chain a `combineLatest` to the `getByCriteria`'s pipe